# Is there a way to show an object in a cell without refreshing the cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want a way to show two UIViews in my cell without having to refresh the cell. Right now I'm using this to refresh it...

```
table.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
```

But I don't want to refresh it at all, because then it reloads all of the information from Parse. Is there a way to show these UIViews without refreshing the cell? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. You can get the visible cell from the table view and call method on the cell which will show the views:

```
let cell = table.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
cell.showMyViews()
```

Comment: @OP you of course have to write that custom show method yourself!

Comment: @OP Also, be aware that your approach is wrong. cellForRow should NOT query parse. that belongs in a domain model.

Comment: @Daij-Djan What do you mean a domain model?

Comment: I think he meant that you have to be sure that cell is visible so that tableView will not query for a new cell by that call.

Comment: there is the M V C pattern, and the table is the view, the VC is the controller and you should have a model. the problem with reloading in cellForRow is that it might be called again or/and the cell is reused...

Comment: @Daij-Djan Ok great! Thanks this is making sense. But I am confused where I should load the information from Parse. Should I make my own custom method to do so? Or do an if statement surrounding the information in the cellForRow?

Comment: make your own objects that keep the state. don't 'blow' up the controller

Comment: @Daij-Djan Ok great! Thanks.